# Is it better to use EFS over EBS when using ELB and multiple instances behing the ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

I have an instance on production and I am planning to attach it to an ELB very soon. So, I will have 3 instances behind the ELB. Is it better to use EFS over EBS for this? If I use EBS, I'll have to configure GIT to replicate the code over all 3 EBS volumes, and if it is EFS, I don't have to do that. But can I get the benefits of ELB when using EFS in this scenario?
Please help.

Comment: That's pretty broad. The question refers to loadbalancing, file storage, and code deployment, and you are asking for "which is better" type answers about their use.  You may need to break this down.

Comment: Sure, I need to use EFS for my 2 instances behind an ELB. How is the load distribution process here. On EBS, the load is distributed to the 2 volumes, whereas in EFS, the entire traffic is towards one file system. So, will I get the benefit of ELB, if opting for EFS?

Comment: They are not exactly related in the way you suggest: ELB has nothing to do with EFS really.  Keep it simple at first. An ELB  for load/availability.  Then use  CodeDeploy for code deployments to an attached EBS volume. EFS is for other use cases - no need here. Also note CodeDeploy is free. https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/pricing/.

Comment: In the simplified way, ELB is used for `balance the loading from clients to servers` and `EFS is kind of NFS`. You can mix them if you know what they are and what are used cases. So ELB is not relative to EFS.